# How to structure TypeScript project with two parts Browser and Server?

Tags: typescript

Suppose we are writing both **Server** and **Browser** code using TypeScript, and we also would like to **Share** some code.

We can achieve that with the following file structure

```
project/
  shared/
    lib.ts
  server/
    shared(symlink)
    server.ts
    tsconfig.json
  client/
    shared(symlink)
    client.ts
    tsconfig.json

  build/
    client/
      build.js
    server/
      shared/
        lib.js
      server.js
```

We can symlink `shared` to both `client` and `server` with separate `tsconfig` and produce two builds. 
For the client - the build would merge everything into single `build/client/build.js` file, for server - it would 
only compile files to `js` without merging it.

To actually build you need to open two terminals and execute in each `tsc --watch server` 
and `tsc --watch client`.

I wonder if there's easier options to do that. And - I would like to avoid any extra stuff like `webpack` etc.

Comment: Use `Lerna` and make it a monorepo